# Type of `==` in Haskell should be `Eq a b => a -> b -> Bool`

Tags: haskell, types, equality, typeclass

The type of `(==)` is `Eq a => a -> a -> Bool` but I can imagine a more general version `Eq a b => a -> b -> Bool` that is false when the types don't match and is just the usual kind of equality when the types match. Why is this not the case?

Comment: Can you give an example where you might use this?  I for one would like to know at compile time if I am asking an obviously answerable question.

Comment: I'm not aware of any parser combinator lib that works over heterogenous streams. Parsec, attoparsec, polyparse, and uu-parsinglib (the ones I've used) certainly don't.

Comment: Why would you want / make a heterogenous stream? Surely everything starts as String or Text, and you want to convert it to your target representation, which is typically a union type - your AST. I can't see where you want or need anything heterogenous.

Comment: I don't see any problems (even type-safety issues) with defining that function using `MultiParamTypeClasses`. It's just not needed that often.

Comment: @davidk01 I can't speak for anyone else here, but I'm not really sure I understand what you're suggesting (what is a heterogenous stream with matchers?). So it's not that I disagree (or agree) with the approach, I just don't understand what you're saying. An example would help, I think.

Comment: @davidk01 I'm not very familiar with TypeScript unfortunately, so I'm not sure where the types don't match. Could you point out a couple lines in particular where this happens? If I'm understanding correctly, this is how I'd implement it in Haskell and I'm not sure where heterogeneous equality would come into play: http://lpaste.net/116405

Comment: @davidk01 That looks equivalent to my lines 54-60.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66829/discussion-between-davidk01-and-david-young).

Comment: @davidk01 Surely the point of a parser is to introduce formal structure and disallow input that doesn't fit the structure. In that sense, something of type `Function Ident [Param]` is more useful to you than some heterogenous `["identifier", [("formal1","type1"),("formal2","type2)]]`. I'm not convinced that avoiding structure gains you anything - it just allows incorrect input to persist for longer. You may well disagree with the structured approach since your example parser simply throws away unconverted input, but I think you should give it a try.

Comment: You should have a go at learning how Haskell's `data` declarations can let you roll a problem-specific datatype that can contain everything need, and you can put in a list as much as you like. It really is much easier and simpler than what you're trying to do. Instead of trying to work around the type system, try working with it. It's really very useful.

Comment: @davidk01 That's a little like visiting Paris, France and insisting on eating at MacDonald's and paying in USD. Why not swap for Euros and experience one of the wold's finest cuisines? It's a pity you lost your earlier willingness to think differently and learn new things. It's also like learning to fly a light aircraft by figuring out how to drive it on the roads.

Comment: I was the one giving practical advice, you were the one shackling yourself to the sacred cow of heterogenous lists and justifying this with your philosophy of programming, where you don't learn things and turn each new language into an old one. If your mental model cannot include a sum type, it's you who are sacrificing your true freedom for a false one. It's like refusing to get in the helecopter because shutting yourself in and strapping yourself to the seat restricts your freedom. Your mental models have been subordinate to the kind of programming languages you're used to for years. Adapt!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can define that in terms of both `Eq` and [`Typeable` from `Data.Typeable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Typeable.html#t:Typeable). We can compare the types of things that are `Typeable` to check that they are the same type.

```
(?==) :: (Eq b, Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> b -> Bool
x ?== y = cast x == Just y
```

`cast` checks that a value of one `Typeable` type is actually the same type as another. It returns `Just` the input if they are the same type or `Nothing` if the types are different.

Here are a few examples demonstrating the desired behavior.

```
> 7 ?== 7
True

> 7 ?== "hello"
False

> 7 ?== 5
False

> (7 :: Int) ?== (7 :: Integer)
False
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I was just going down this rabbit-hole when I noticed your answer.

Answer (score 7):

`(==) :: Eq a b => a -> b -> Bool` wouldn't be of as much use as you'd think.

To determine an instance of 2-parameter `Eq`, you need to know *both* types (well enough to match an instance). Any callers of this `==` would need to either concretely know `a` and `b`, or pass the constraint on in their interface; then their own callers either need to know what `a` and `b` are, or pass the constraint on.... at some point the `Eq` instance has to be selected, rather than provided via a constraint, and that involves knowing `a` and `b` **at compile time**.

At that point, why would you bother? If you know `a` and `b` are the same, then a single parameter `Eq` is enough to compare them. And if you know they are different, then you know the answer is `False` and you don't need *any* instance to tell you that. And if you *don't* know whether they are the same or different, then by definition you don't know enough to select an `Eq` instance, so you can't call `==` (or an `Eq`-constrained function) at all!

So this wouldn't help you get an `a` and `b` of unknown types (that implement equality) from separate sources and then compare them. They would have had to come together with an `Eq a b` instance, which is effectively a compile-time proof of whether they are the same type or not,

The `Typeable` version in @Cirdec's answer is very different, and much more useful. Here each type *independentlly* supports `Typeable` and one of them supports single-parameter `Eq`; you can get these two values from two different sources where you don't know if they are the same or not, but you know that you can check the type of each; the `a` source has to know `a` well enough to select a `Typeable` instance, and the `b` source has to know `b` well enough to select `Typeable` and `Eq` instances, but neither source has to know anything about the *other* type, and no code has to know both types at once well enough to tell whether they are the same (at compile time). The 2-parameter `Eq` forces both types to be known at once, somewhere, which would make it near-worthless.

Comment: You might want to mention that Cirdec's (unavoidable) `Typeable` constraints don't come for free—unless they specialize away at compile time (so you don't need `?==`), they involve passing two extra dictionaries around at run-time.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the philosophical answer to your question is that Haskell in its nature resembles math, and when we put on our math hats on and define equality for mathematical objects, we usually consider the two objects to be of the same type. E.g. look at how set equality is defined.

And now, does the set of natural numbers equal the natural 6? or let's go wild -- does chair equal the integer -7? etc. While I'm tempted to let my intuition take over and scream "Of course not!", I really can't say that, because the question itself is invalid, it's all very undefined. Equality between sets and a natural is undefined. Equality between chairs and an integer is undefined.

Does it mean you can't define it? Nope, go ahead.
But it's just not a very popular approach, so the base library's choice is very understandable.

---

As a reply to your comment, it is correct. As it happens, sets are so primitive that we can represent just about anything with them. That's just an example, and I don't know if you could argue similarly if we pick something else, but let's ride it anyways.

For set A to be equal to set B we need that:

1. Every element in A exists in B
2. Every element in B exists in A

Sticking to it very simply, does the set {1,2,3} equal to 7? I don't know, because saying that an element exists in 7 is undefined, the question is invalid.

But let's take your approach, and do as you say: take 7, put it in a nice dress to lift it and call it set C, and let's even assume that C equals set D to show how right your are. You made it possible to ask for equality between 7 and another set, *ultimately*. But I just want you to notice how we had to work our way to make it a set in the first place, before we could do that. That's exactly what Haskell would want you to do, if possible. With sets in math, it's almost always possible.

So both in Haskell and in math we (still) can't truly even ask:

```
(a :: Set) == (7 :: Natural)
```

However, in both Haskell and math we can lift it first just so we can look at it differently, and then we can ask:

```
(liftN :: Natural -> Set) (7 :: Natural) == (a :: Set)
```

The RHS is the set C, of course.

And the point of this answer is that Haskell is just being idiomatic in common mathematical terms by defining equality the way it does.

Comment: @davidk01, Haskell is based more on type theory than on set theory.

Comment: @davidk01, yes, that's probably so, but you can't necessarily expect it to be a particularly *nice* isomorphism.

Comment: @davidk01 "Change of representations is a common enough operation in most of mathematics", and it's a common enough operation in Haskell. And you do it explicitly in either case.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell's opinion is that it only makes sense to check equality of two values of same type, i.e., checking equality of two different typed values is meaningless and very likely means you're doing something wrong in your program. This is why the type of (==) is what it is.

Generally speaking, this is what it means to be working in a powerful type system such as Haskell's. It's designed to help write better and more meaningful programs.